# Why is camera.onAutoFocus() returning false on Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a routine to take a picture using the Camera class, which implements the Camera.AutoFocusCallback method. I've never had an issue with this until using the Samsung Galaxy S6, and in this instance the success variable sometimes returns false (not always, but mostly, without any regular pattern that I can see).

```
camera.autoFocus(this);

@Override
public void onAutoFocus(final boolean success, final Camera camera) {
    // returns false for Galaxy S6
}
```

I'm struggling to know what I can do to prevent this, or to understand what is causing it, any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: it´s maybe a defective cam. test if the autofocus works correctly:open phone dial pad -->enter this code: *#0*#-->hardware menu opens, select camera module to test ("Mega Cam", not sure could be a similar name)...

Comment: Oh no, this is from all of our users with this device! It's definitely device specific.

Comment: ok, I found some other post, where it was caused by a too large preview size, only on a specific device too, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317311/droid-x-camera-autofocus-callback-always-returns-false

Comment: Yes I've seen that post, and indeed it seems to be the only other vaguely related question. But I've played around with the suggestions there, without any success.

Comment: @androidneil Have you come up with a solution yet?

Comment: @Gunhan No, unfortunately not. There seems to be a hardware problem with the S6 (I now have one to test with and it also has the issue). Google search 'samsung galaxy s6 focus problem'. I'm not sure how to get around this as I can't lock focus from the code, therefore can't take a good picture.

Comment: @androidneil hi again, I solved the problem by updating my sources to the latest vision api samples which you can find here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader It seems that they've changed quite a bit of the samples. But it didn't took that much time to update my project. And also make sure to pass "true" to the createCameraSource method for the autoFocus parameter.

Comment: @Gunhan thanks for the tip... please can you tell me what you changed to help with my specific problem?

Comment: Before that change, i was using java reflection to enable the autofocus which doesn't work on s6, public static boolean cameraFocus(CameraSource cameraSource, String focusMode) {..} now they added this functionality to their camera.builder builder = builder.setFocusMode(autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);